# How to change font color of a selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just need some help on how to change the font color of the title for the current div being selected.

See my code below:

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <p  id="hideshow1" class="btn">Photography</p>
                <p  id="hideshow2" class="btn">Graphics</p>
                <hr class="small">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="photography" class="photography">
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">     
            <hr class="small">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="photography-item">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="photo" title="Honda City 98'" href="imgs/pics/resized/car1.jpg"><img src="imgs/pics/resized/car1.jpg" alt="" /></a>                                         
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <hr class="small">
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                    <p  id="hideshow1" class="btn">Photography</p>
                    <p  id="hideshow2" class="btn">Graphics</p>
                    <hr class="small">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="graphics" class="graphics">
        <div class="container">     
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">     
            <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="graphics-item">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="photo" title="Honda City 98'" href="imgs/pics/resized/car1.jpg"><img src="imgs/pics/resized/car1.jpg" alt="" /></a>                                         
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="small">
                </div>      
            </div>  
     </div>
```

JS

```
$("#hideshow1").click(function(){
    $("#photography").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#graphics").slideUp("slow");

  });

   $("#hideshow2").click(function(){
    $("#graphics").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#photography").slideUp("slow");
  });
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click Photography, it will change the font color and when I click Graphics, the photography color would go back to black and graphics would now be the colored font.

Comment: You can simply toggle a class on the divs that changes the color. You will have to toggle the class on click for the appropriate div. And use that class to change the color of the font.

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/changehtmlelementcolor.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function chgfont(type){

    // document.write("<input type=\"button\"  id=\"hideshow2\" name=\"hideshow2\" value=\"red\" class=\"btn\" onclick=\"chgfont('B');\"><input type=\"button\"  id=\"hideshow1\" name=\"hideshow1\" value=\"blue\" class=\"btn\" onclick=\"chgfont('A');\"> ");
  
     if(type=="A"){
       document.getElementById("colorA").style.color ="blue";        
      // document.write("<font color=\"blue\">Font colors is blue</font>");
         
     }else{
       document.getElementById("colorA").style.color ="red";     
      // document.write("<font color=\"red\">Font colors is red</font>");
     }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                  <input type="button"  id="hideshow1" name="hideshow1" value="blue" class="btn" onclick="chgfont('A');">
                  <input type="button"  id="hideshow2" name="hideshow2" value="red" class="btn" onclick="chgfont('B');">
                    <hr class="small">
                  <div id="colorA">
    Colored By Santa
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a little different formation of your function. Select the `.btn` elements and, depending on the clicked element, get the id and perform your actions.

As for the font color, write up a css rule giving the desired color and simply add, or remove this class form the respective elements:

jQuery

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {

   var that = $(this);
   var id = that.attr('id');

   //Remove .colored class form all .btn elements
   $('.btn').removeClass('colored');

   //Add .colored class to the clicked element
   that.addClass('colored');

   var ph = $("#photography");
   var gr = $("#graphics");

   //Permorm the appropriate action depending on the clicked id
   if (id == '#hideshow1') {
      ph.slideToggle("slow");
      gr.slideUp("slow");
   } else if (id == '#hideshow2') {
      gr.slideToggle("slow");
      ph.slideUp("slow");
   }

});
```

CSS

```
.colored { color:red }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to do this. but it doesnt work. Apologies tho, I'm very new to jQuery.

I don't get this part.

` var that = $(this);
   var id = that.attr('id');

   //Remove .colored class form all .btn elements
   $('.btn').removeClass('colored');

   //Add .colored class to the clicked element
   that.addClass('colored');`

Should I create a class under colored?

Comment: This code adds and removes class .colored, you must create this class in your css in order to give the desired color